# Cannot play html5 audio on ipad safari

Tags: ipad, html, safari, html5-audio

I am unable to play html5 audio on iPad Safari..i have tried

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.type = "audio/mpeg";
    audio.src = audioUrl;         
    x.appendChild(audio);
audio.load()
    audio.play();
```

and

```
x.innerHTML = '<audio autoplay=autoplay><source src="'+audioUrl + '" type=audio/mpeg /></audio>';
```

I am able to play on desktop Safari, but on the iPad it says, cannot play movie...

I am using ios 4.3

One important thing which i might think i need to look at is adding mime type to htaccess..though not sure how and if that is the issue...But just to add, i can play the fallback mp3 using embed on older browsers..so does that mean even the html5 audio should work without the need of adding the MIME type?

Please help me. Thank u..

Comment: Checkout the HTML5 audio player at http://mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: Well..the reason i am using html5 is bcoz it helps in reducing use of any 3rd party code/plug in..also i do not want any player to be visible..just want to play audio in the background..so wanted to know why the above code is not working for me..do I have to make any MIME settings on the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some video and audio types are served up by certain browsers with no configuration on your part (which is likely why mp3 files are being served), but you will need to add a mapping to .htaccess in order for the MPEG audio to work for you. Just open your .htaccess file for your site and add (something like) the following line

`AddType audio/mpeg .mp3`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx a lot for ur reply..My only question is if the mp3 is already playing via <embed> tag, should the same mp3 not automatically play when called via the html5 <audio>..i mean just the tag is changing..so does it still need adding to the htaccess ? Also the file type i want to play is mp3..

Comment: sorry, changed that line to .mp3. I would try adding that line to htaccess and see if it works. I wouldn't be surprised if playing works via embed but not audio, so its worth a shot.